# Boost is installed where on my Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost

I download Boost 1.54 tar from Boost website and then followed the instructions as detailed here [1].

In particular, I wanted to install my boost library in the folder

```
$HOME/BOOST
```

using this:

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$HOME/BOOST
```

But after the installation, this folder is still empty. Why is that?

P.S.: Boost installation at the end said:

```
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_wave.a
...failed updating 62 targets...
...skipped 18 targets...
...updated 1004 targets...
```

[1] http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Comment: why aren't you using apt-get install libboost libboost-dev?

Comment: I did that, but for some reason, I was still not able to locate exactly where the headers and .so files were located.

Comment: Have you tried running `locate boost`?

Comment: Probably `/usr/local`.  That's the default when installing most software from source.

Comment: It looks like it has installed right in the folder where your boost source files were. Try looking for "boost" folder within the starting location. Also, you should run "b2 install" from the same location where you run bootstrap.sh just to be sure. If nothing works, then most likely your setup has already reached "/usr/local/include" - this should contain "boost" folder.

Comment: you don't really need to locate it at all. When you compile, use `pkg-config libboost-dev --cflags` for the compiler and `pkg-config libboost --libs` for the linker.

Answer (score 22):

If you use the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

to install the boost library on your Ubuntu distribution, then you can find the location using this command

`whereis boost`.

Typically it's stored in the location `/usr/include/boost`.

Comment: in /usr/include/boost , i find only .hpp files, where are .so and .a files (libraries) ?

Comment: You might need to check /usr/local/lib or /lib directories on your system if you need to find a specific so, you can also run the command sudo find / -name "*boost*.so.*" this will give you the location of your boost so files in case they are stored on your system

Comment: In my case I have entries in `/usr/include/boost` but nothing else is found with your `find` command.

Answer (score 22):

The boost library files are in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. You'll see a whole bunch of other libraries there as well.