# Cannot find c++ boost header files on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using apt installation

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-20.04

I have just upgraded my server to ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I am now trying to various different code packages on it and receiving errors relating to the boost installation.

Rather than building from source, I have installed boost 1.71.0 using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

However, when I try and compile code I am getting errors such as:

```
fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp: No such file or directory
   15 | #include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have spent the last 3 hours trying to find those hpp files with no success. There is nothing in:

```
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/lib/
/usr/include/boost *doesn't exist*
```

Any idea what could be wrong?
I'm trying to avoid installing boost from source, rather than the Ubuntu package but do I have to?

Comment: Have you checked: [Boost is installed where on my Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842045/boost-is-installed-where-on-my-ubuntu)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep yes I have seen that stackoverflow. That refers to the default as `/usr/include/boost` but there's nothing there. Additionally: `locate boost` shows /usr/share/boost-build/ as a folder with files, but that contains just a huge number of .jam files. I've not found any .hpp files.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` succeed? Try it again and see the output message.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I have done many installations.  `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.71.0.0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
` but I have also used `remove` and `install` and even `reinstall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue.

Turns out that because I had a previous boost installation from a manual installation (before I upgraded to 20.04 LTS) and had deleted those files manually, further re-installs via apt were not recreating the files in `usr/include/`, due to other packages relating to boost still installed in the system.

The recovery was to run `apt list --installed '*boost*'` and then uninstall any of those linked packages.
After doing that running `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev` recreated the /usr/include/boost directory with all the header files.

This process was listed in the answer on: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161393/i-deleted-usr-include-boost-installing-libboost-all-dev-wont-bring-headers-ba